# Get Memberships Of User

Tags: powershell

I have a very simple question but for some reason I can't seem to get my head around it. 
I need a line of code that could be ran as a user from a client and lists all the "memeber of" groups from the AD (ONLY FOR THIS CURRENT USER). similar to

```
Get-ADGroupMember -identity "domain admins" -Recursive | foreach{ get-aduser $_} | select SamAccountName,objectclass,name
```

I would like the result to be listed.

I either need a way to import the AD module on a client computer or another way to contact the DC and get the users current "memeber of" groups.

/Niklas

Comment: Do you mean that if I were a user that you want me to pull my groups with one line of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the best way for my needs but [CB.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30484660/3829407) worked as well!

```
[ADSISEARCHER]"samaccountname=$($env:USERNAME)").Findone().Properties.memberof -replace '^CN=([^,]+).+$','$1'
```

I can then keep using this output in my code

Comment: I forget about ADSI but this would be the best solution if you don't want to have to install the plugin on every desktop.

Answer (score 0):

you can use dos command line:

```
net user /domain %username%
```

Comment: This might be better as I can't expect _everyone_ would have access to the ad cmdlets

Comment: I put them in our Desktop/laptop images here just so they would always be there for scripting. :)

Comment: I have a couple of issues with this answer. First, this command could be run in powershell, but not as it is currently presented. The OP did ask for a PS solution. Second, the output would need to be parsed to simply get a list of the groups. Third, the return from the command truncates the group names if they are over 22 characters long.

Comment: I could. I thought I would do the polite thing and give a comment and the chance for you to improve your answer first.

Comment: @EBGreen I will not improve my answer, I like the one of the O.P. owner. But thank for be so kind :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be with

`Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -identity "Username"`

Now this also means that you would have to have the active directory module loaded which you can find more information on its use on Technet [Get-ADPrincipalGroupMember](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617259.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to produce a list, make a call to the command prompt as I find this works well, although it does truncate group names:

```
net user %username% /DOMAIN
```

If you want to programmatically get them and easily *do* something with that data, you'll want to rely on the **Active Directory cmdlets**.

To determine if you have these readily available in Powershell, you'll need to run the following command:

```
Get-Module –ListAvailable
```

If you don't see **ActiveDirectory** in the list you will need to first download and install the [Windows Management Framework](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855) and import the module yourself:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
```

Once that's done I believe this command should do the trick:

```
(Get-ADUser userName –Properties MemberOf | Select-Object MemberOf).MemberOf
```

Hopefully that gets you started. I'm fairly certain that there's more than one way to accomplish this with Powershell.  Take a look at the [Microsoft TechNet documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee617195.aspx) to see if you can find something that better suits your needs.

Personally I have only ever needed to query AD group memberships ad-hoc for diagnostic purposes and have always relied on Get-ADUser or the command line call, depending on the target audience of the resulting data.